# Webview becomes blank sometimes only after suspend and resume

Tags: android, webview

In my Android application, I am using WebView to load a page from Server. When app is on this webview, if I press home button and then switch back to my app, WebView appears fine. No issues till here. 
If after pressing home button, if I open some of other apps like a browser and then launch some video in youtube and open some online news paper and then switch back to my app, then WebView appears blank.

I don't think there is any simple coding mistake as if I switch back immediately to my app, then there is no issue. But it goes blank, only if I open browser (Chrome) app and open some sites and then switch to my app.

Surprisingly on this blank screen, if I tap here and there, then keyboard comes up. It looks to me that, when tap happens on the area of screen, where there exists an edit box in server page (though it is not visible), key board is popping up.

From debugger, in my DialogFragment's onResume, I could see that WebView's visibility is VIEW.VISIBLE only, even when it shows blank screen in the device.

How can I debug or nail down this issue?
Any idea, why this could be happening?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try on the your DialogFragment onPause :

```
mWebView.onPause();
```

and on your DialogFragment onResume :

```
mWebview.onResume();
```

I had a similar issue with a video inside the webview that freeze it.

Comment: Yes, DialogFragment's onPause and onResume are @Overriden and calling super from it and then mWebView.onPause and .onResume respectivitely.

Comment: I have also @Override the onLowMemory to see if that is getting called when my webview is going blank. But, that is not getting called.